# How to listen to data change in MySql?

Tags: mysql, unity-game-engine, network-programming

I am trying to make multiplayer turn based game in Unity. I want to store first client's move in database and in second client's application look for the database and update game board with first client's move.I want to know that is there other way except regularly check for value change in database?

Answer (score 0):

Databases are used to store data only, like a big file you can access when you want with queries (SQL). You can make a timer who track changes every X ms but i don't think this is the right way when you'r building real time application or games over networking.

I don't know how your unity networking is. But i'll try to explain how you need to implement :
Unity networking and games in general are based on direct tcp connection between client and server part. What you need to do is to keep your game state (like "moves") in the server side, that way you will be able to notify every client that "PLAYER X MOVE THERE".
You can use a database to save your server side state every X second if you want as an "anti crash device".

A database will be more usefull if its used for no real time data like scores history or user informations.

I hope I was clear enough in my awnser :)